# Invoking a predicate throws NullReferenceException in condition

Tags: c#, predicate

I have the following method but when I invoke that method I get a NullReferenceException.

```
public IQueryable<TItem> Query {get; set;}

public void AddCriteria<TSource>(TSource source, Func<IQueryable<TItem>, TSource, IQueryable<TItem>> func, Predicate<TSource> condition)
{
    if(condition(source))
    {
        Query = func(Query, source);
    }
}
```

I call it using the following line of code.

```
searchFilter.AddCriteria(searchCriteria, (u,v) => u.Where(p=>p.Field1.equals(true)), p => p.Field2.Specified && p.Field2.Name.Equals(Settings.Default.NameKey));
```

I'm trying to have a null safe check before apply the **condition** to the **source**. Do you know how to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: That code doesn't compile. Also, how do you call that method? We just have to guess now.

Comment: What is `Query`? Where do you get it from?

Comment: The way I call is not important because the null check needs to be here. But I will change the question.

Comment: But what do you want to null-check? Why doesn't a simple `if (x == null)` work?

Comment: @Igor I know what is a null reference but this is not that simple.

Comment: Yes, it is that simple @duknust

Comment: No because the condition is not null and the source is neither. The condition applied to the source throws a nullreference but I can't test if one or the other is null

Comment: Then you should fix the code in the condition, right?